# QGIS open tif file larger than 10 GB, '*.tif is not a supported raster data source'

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

When trying to use QGIS to open a tif file larger than 10GB, I encountered an error says "*.tif is not a supported raster data source." Is there any way or other software to open large tif files?

Comment: QGIS should be able to open also larger that 4 GB tiff images (BigTIFF) if is it compiled with GDAL version that has the support. What is your GDAL version (check with `gdalinfo --version` . Does gdalinfo show the same error?

Comment: I got 'GDAL 1.7.3, released 2010/11/10' with `gdalinfo --version`. Does it mean that I should firstly recompile the GDAL lib, then re-install QGIS? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: BigTIFF support has been in GDAL at least in version 1.6 through libtiff 4.0 so your version should be high enough. I recommend still updating to 2.0 or 1.11. But did you already check your image with gdalinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html?

Comment: Oh, I tried `gdalinfo gd-ll.tif` and then got ```ERROR 4: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by this
version of GDAL and libtiff.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/home/Simon/Projects/Forrest/Data/Qingdao_1508/figures/qd-ll.tif'.``` I guess I have to recompile all of them? I used `yum install gdal`. Is there any convenient way to install gdal with bigTiff supported? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Linux repositories but I believe that BigTIFF support has been the default for years and if you find a ready packages for GDAL version >1.9 they probably work for you.